# Flash: Function is triggered more than once

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, cc

I am trying to make a little blackjack game.
I ran in to a problem, ant I cant find my mistake.
When you want an extra card the first round, you get one card. (You have to press a button to get it), but in the second round, when you click the button the function triggers twice, in the third round 3 times and so on.
Between the rounds I remove everything from screen.

Here is the function that trigger to often:

```
function extracard() {
                    var cextra: int = drawcard(cardpos, 400, true);
                    trace("drew extra card");
                    if (cextra == 1) {
                        var valchooser3: _1or11 = new _1or11();
                        addChild(valchooser3);
                        valchooser3.one.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, choose3_1);
                        valchooser3.eleven.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, choose3_11);
                        valchooser3.x = 280;
                        valchooser3.y = 380;
                        //chipsandcardonscreen.push(valchooser3);
                        function choose3_1() {
                            valchooser3.one.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, choose3_1);
                            removeChild(valchooser3);
                        }
                        function choose3_11() {
                            valchooser3.eleven.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, choose3_11);
                            playerpoints += 10;
                            trace(playerpoints);
                            removeChild(valchooser3);
                        }
                    }
                    cardpos += 150;
                    playerpoints += cextra;
                }
```

The drawcard function:

```
    function drawcard(xpos: int, ypos: int, faceup: Boolean): int {
            var rand: int = Math.floor(Math.random() * shoe.length);
            var newcard: Karte = shoe[rand];
            addChild(newcard);
            trace("aktuelle Karte:" + getChildAt(numChildren - 1).name);
            trace("draw:" + numChildren);
            newcard.x = xpos;
            newcard.y = ypos;
            if (!faceup) {
                toturn.push(newcard);
                newcard.turncard();
            } 
            shoe.splice(rand, 1);
            return newcard.getcardval();
            if (shoe.length <= 0) {
                trace("shoe empty");
                realshoe.gotoAndStop(2);
            }
```

And the remove everything function

```
            function realreset() { 

            canBet = true;

            while (numChildren != 0) {
                removeChild(getChildAt(0));
            } 
            startsinglegame();
        }
```

Does anyone know a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: You are not showing the relevant code. Somewhere in your code something is calling 'extracard'. Voted down for not making the effort to show the relevant code.

Comment: I downvoted for the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include the necessary code, but what's most likely happening is that you are registering your click handler (that eventually calls your `extracard` function) an additional time each round (which is why for the `n`'th round you are getting `n` extra cards).

The code is something like:

```
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, extracard);
```

Now if you click your button 3x, it will call `extracard` 3x.

To ensure this doesn't happen, try something like

```
if (!button.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK)) {
    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, extracard);
}
```

Comment: extracard is not actually a listener for anything.

Comment: @BotMaster - you're right. Presumably it gets called via some proxy function after the "button" is clicked though. Will clarify in my answer.

Comment: my guess is that the listener is in a frame and each time the playhead comes back to that frame the listener is added again but since this is a new frame it doesn't override the first listener but keeps on adding treating the listener as a new method.